# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Tags: android, json, android-studio, flutter, jsonparser

```
    void makeLoginReq() async {
    String url = 'https://travel.prabidhee.com/api/login';
    Map map = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    };
    print(await apiRequest(url, map));
    final response = await apiRequest(url, map);
    print(response);
    List<Map> reply = json.decode(response);
    List<UserModelData> result = reply.map((item) => new UserModelData.fromJson(item)).toList();
    print(result[0].accessToken);
  }

  Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    var reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    httpClient.close();
    print(reply);
    return (reply);
  }
}
```

This is the function for a login request in remote server. After Login json responses are decoded and stored in reply variable. Now i want to extract each elements like access_token , token_type... from the response. How can I do that ?

[image: Debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception reads, you're problem is that you are casting a map into a list, which is not possible. Just as you can't cast a String to an integer or as you can't treat a rainworm as a horse and ride on it to the sunset.
The question of course is why that happens:
The line `json.decode(response)` returns a map but the variable that you want to assign this map may only store a list.
For example, if your response looks something like this:

```
{
    "body": [
        "Alisa",
        "Alex",
        "Boby",
        "Monica"
    ]
}
```

Then your `json.decode(response)` is going to be `Map<String, List>("body" to ["Alisa", ...])`, so body is mapped to the names.
Assuming that you want to isolate the list from the other json, you can just do `json.decode(response).get("body")` or if youre json looks different, you can also get all values or keys in the map by calling `json.decode(response).values()` or `json.decode(response).keys()`.

Comment: It would be so helpful if you can edit the above code